# class name in missing with Log4j2 - spring boot 1.3.7

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

class name is not printing log. Find below log4j2.xml and pom.xml. please help on this. i tried following options

1. with spring boot starter logging - not working
2. with out spring boot starter logging with log4j2 - not working

Please check the console. first four lines contains class name but after that it is not comming

**Log4j2.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logpattern">%d{DATE} [${sys:PID}] [%t] %-5p %c-[%L] %X - %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${logpattern}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Sample</name>
    <description>Sample Description</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.valuemomentum</groupId>
            <artifactId>ratingService3X</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.woodstox/woodstox-core-asl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Calling ifoundry - dependency jars -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-kernel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-adb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-transport-http -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-transport-local -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-xmlbeans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-jaxws -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/javax.el-api -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.el</groupId> <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId> 
            <version>3.0.0</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/el-impl -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId> <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId> 
            <version>2.2</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/javax.el -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/fop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graylog2.log4j2/log4j2-gelf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graylog2.log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j2-gelf</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>internal</id>
            <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://10.50.255.230:8888/repository/internal/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

**console**

```
20 Sep 2016 18:58:14,864 [9684] [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment-[346] {} - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
20 Sep 2016 18:58:15,136 [9684] [main] INFO  org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version-[66] {} - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
20 Sep 2016 18:58:15,315 [9684] [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect-[145] {} - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
20 Sep 2016 18:58:15,569 [9684] [main] INFO  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory-[47] {} - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
20 Sep 2016 18:58:16,195 [9684] [main] INFO  -[45] {} - HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean called
20 Sep 2016 18:58:19,573 [9684] [main] INFO  -[99] {} - requestString::: {
  "auth" : {
```

Comment: so what exactly is missing?

Comment: class name. please check console here first four logs, class name is available but after that it is not available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the layout pattern, replace lowercase `%c` (logger name) with uppercase `%C` (class where the logger was called).